# Why everything is treat as file in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux

why everything is treated as file to Linux.i can't understand why everything is treated as file in Linux in fact hardware system is also treated as file in Linux

Comment: inherited from unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Comment: You might meant Plan9, in Linux not everything is a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is treated as a file in Linux because of two main reasons:-
Convenience:- Treating everything as file makes it convenient to write programs based on hardware.For example , you may send some command to your mouse with a simple read() function as if you are reading a file(details are complex obviously).
Treating hardware as a file makes in simpler to enforce permissions on hardware similar to a file through the use of umasks.

Comment: what does "program based on hardware" meant ? Elaborate this

Comment: Program based on hardware means softwares that may deal directly with the hardware e.g. a driver.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with i/o operations. If you have some i/o devices you can use the pipe operator on them.  It is also very handy if you want to read data from them. But i'm not sure if this is the only reason.